# Images downloaded from mysql data base does not show when rendrering them to pdf

Tags: html, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, flying-saucer

I am working on a project with thymeleaf, Spring boot and mysql database.

I am saving images into database (Byte[]).

When getting them from the db, with byte[] converted into base64, It displays on the html pages but when I want to export to PDF, I get nothing.

```
List<DBFile> dBFiles = fileService.getFilesByPaziente(username);
        String pic = "data:image/jpeg;Base64, " + Base64.encodeBase64String(dBFiles.get(1).getData());
        variables.put("pic", pic);
        context.setVariables(variables);

        String html = templateEngine.process("pazienti/pdf_scheda_template", context);
        String outputFolder = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "thymeleaf.pdf";
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFolder);
        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
        renderer.setDocumentFromString(html);
        renderer.layout();
        renderer.createPDF(outputStream);
        outputStream.close();
```

```
<img th:src="${pic} " alt="hey" name="images" width="300"></img>
```

When logging the html String with the context I get this

```
    <img src="data:image/jpeg;Base64, /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgA...." alt="hey" width="300"></img>
```

To sumerize,
images displays very well from db to html but parsing html to pdf, they doesn't show.

Comment: Your image tag looks fine. But am not sure if your Base64 String's complete length is displayed ( In short not sure if its valid ). Use a online base64 to image tool to first verify whether the image is properly rendered. for example use this tool -> https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter

Comment: It is displayed all. Just I've put a part of it in the example and I checked it with a converter.